# Display the selected item among many shuffled items

Tags: php, select, random, parameters

Here it is an `array` with four numbers! These numbers are shuffled every time we refresh the page.

```
<?php
  $numbers = array("one", "two", "three", "four");
  if($numbers) {
    shuffle($numbers);
?>
<p><?php echo $numbers[0] ?></p>
<?php
  }
?>
```

However, I'd like to set up a `select` field where I could make select one of these four options and display only one of them when selected! For instance: if I select number three, so the page will reload and select only the number three.

```
<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option>Select</option>
  <option value="?number=one">One</option>
  <option value="?number=two">Two</option>
  <option value="?number=three">Three</option>
  <option value="?number=four">Four</option>
</select>
```

Thank you!

Comment: To be honest, that is not exactly what I need! The select fields are just a sample! My mistake, sorry! In fact, what I need to output is to display the selected number. I can have either four numbers or thousand numbers looping and getting shuffled between that everytime the page is loaded. However, if the user wants to view the specific number (ie number three) printed on screen, just select the number three and the page is refreshed again showing the number three. Got it??

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, all you have to do is itterate through your `$numbers` array

```
echo "<select>";
foreach($numbers as $num) {
    echo "<option value='?number={$num}'>{$num}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

If I may ask, why have the `?value=NUMBER` ? How are you going to access it? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @CaioFerrari please add these comments to your question

Comment: @CaioFerrari look at **cvsguimaraes**'s answer. That's what you'd do and I won't write it out as he's already answered it :)